# '%' python is giving me a "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I've downloaded the exact version this text asked me to however the '%' is giving me a problem.

```
x = raw_input('Enter an integer:')
if x%2 == 0:
   print ''
   print 'Even'
else:
   print ''
   print 'Odd'
print 'Done with conditional'
```

It is only the '%' operator giving me a problem. Any other operator and the script runs fine. I've read that the version matters because '%' can also be 'string interpolation operator' but like I said I believe the version I have matches my text. WHAT DO I DO NEXT?

Thanks and yes I have pretty much just picked up my first book on programming.

Answer (score 7):

The [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function returns a string, not an integer. To change it to an integer, you have to call the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer:'))
```

Note that an error will be raised if you input anything other than a number.

What python thinks you're doing is trying to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) with the `%` operator. As there are no `"%"` in the string you input, the error "not all arguments converted during string formatting" is raised.

Comment: @OP You might use `%` in the manner that Python THINKS you're using it in by doing `x = "It costs $%.2f"` and `x % 2` which would give you `It costs $2.00`. Of course you're not doing that, but since `x` is a string, Python ASSUMES that you are.